# Django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus is not rendering datepicker properly

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

**I am facing with the problem that my datetimepicker is not loading at all.**

Just in my template, the datetime field loads the current date and time when i press the calendar icon as the image shows.

[image]

Despite following the installation steps from here : https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/ and checking other answers in stackoverflow i did not manage to find the solution.

I think the problem has to do with the imports and their priority.

my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}       
{% bootstrap_css %}         
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}  


{% block page-title %}Creation of Process Note{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-6 offset-md-3">

  <form class="well" method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

<br>
        {% buttons %}

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
               Submit
          </button>
      {% endbuttons %}

  </form>

{{ form.media }}

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

in settings.py

```
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}
```

In my base.html the appearence of the imports is:

Inside head

```
<link href="/static/theme/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/static/theme/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...

Inside footer

```
<script src="/static/theme/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

...

my model

```
class Case_Notes(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField("Creation Date", null=True,blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Appointment Date", null=True,blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField("Notes",max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

my form

```
class ProcessNotesForm(ModelForm):
    notes= CharField(required=False,widget=Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":20}))
    class Meta:
        model = Case_Notes
        fields = ("date","notes",)
        widgets = {
            'date': DateTimePickerInput(), # default date-format %m/%d/%Y will be used
        }
```

Why datepicker widget in the form field is not rendering?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: can you try with changing the place of data field:  date=DateTimePickerInput() after notes before class Meta in your ModelForm.

Comment: @MaestroFJP , no that's the weird thing

Comment: According to the documentation, no errors anywhere indicates it's the location of the `{{ form.media }}`: https://django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Troubleshooting.html#no-errors-anywhere-but-the-calendar-does-not-show-up

Comment: @ytsejam this didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://monim67.github.io/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/configure/), the `{{ form.media }}` needs to follow right under the `{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}` in your template file.

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

{{ form.media }}
```

Comment: I changed the order of form.media but nothing changed. Moreover, the calendar icon disappear in that case

Comment: No, again nothing appeared in the console

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I'm having the same issue, have all the documented code in the template, but the form.media tag doesn't show in page source and I'm puzzled.

Answer (score -1):

Addition to {{ form.media }} you use tuple instead of an array in the fields Meta in the ModelForm:

```
class ProcessNotesForm(ModelForm):
    notes= CharField(required=False,widget=Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":20}))
    class Meta:
        model = Case_Notes
        fields = ["date", "notes" ] # change this ("date","notes",)
        widgets = {
            'date': DateTimePickerInput(), # default date-format %m/%d/%Y will be used
        }
```

Comment: this is not working. I think tuple is needed anyways,

Comment: sorry but it is written "you use tuple instead of an array in the fields Meta in the ModelForm:". and you declare tuple is needed again ? I quite did not understand your concern.